# React native victory chart not working in release mode while working in debug mode

Tags: react-native, victory-charts

I need assistance related an issue i have facing. I am using victory native charts to show line chart. when i run the application and select debug JS remotely, it is running and this result is shown.

[image]

But when i turn off debug mode it crashes and show this.

[image]

I am using this code to show the chart.

```
<VictoryChart scale={{ x: "time" }} domain={{ x: [minDate, maxDate] }} height={350}>
    <VictoryLine
        style={{
            data: { stroke: "blue" }
        }}
        data={chartData}
        x="date"
        y="a"
    />
    <VictoryLine
        style={{
            data: { stroke: "green" }
        }}
        data={chartData}
        x="date"
        y="b"
    />
    <VictoryLine
        style={{
            data: { stroke: "red" }
        }}
        data={chartData}
        x="date"
        y="c"
    />
</VictoryChart>
```

I am stuck in this issue if anyone faced this issue and solved it let me know.

Thanks in advance.

This is the sample data.

`chartData = [
{date: 'Sun Sep 16 2018 12:00:01 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)', a: 107, b: 84, c: 23},
{date: 'Sat Sep 15 2018 12:00:01 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)', a: 95, b: 78, c: 17},
{date: 'Fri Sep 14 2018 12:00:01 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)', a: 83, b: 67, c: 16},
{date: 'Thu Sep 13 2018 12:00:02 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)', a: 92, b: 80, c: 12},
{date: 'Wed Sep 12 2018 12:00:01 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)', a: 81, b: 63, c: 18},
{date: 'Tue Sep 11 2018 12:00:15 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)', a: 105, b: 92, c: 13},
{date: 'Mon Sep 10 2018 12:00:01 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)', a: 122, b: 93, c: 29},
{date: 'Sun Sep 09 2018 12:00:01 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)', a: 79, b: 66, c: 13},
{date: 'Sat Sep 08 2018 12:00:06 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)', a: 64, b: 53, c: 11},
{date: 'Fri Sep 07 2018 12:00:01 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)', a: 62, b: 50, c: 12},
{date: 'Thu Sep 06 2018 12:00:01 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)', a: 83, b: 59, c: 24}
];`

versions:

```
react: "^16.3.1"
react-native: "^0.55.4"
react-native-svg: "^6.5.2"
victory-native: "^30.3.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the domain on x axis does have string date not date, so i converted into date and it is working.

But still i am not sure how it was working in debug mode.